# How to remove existing and add onsubmit in form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this HTML to create a form:

```
<form name="search" id="myForm" onsubmit="return existingfunc()" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" title="Search">
</form>
```

I can change the form's name via jQuery using `$('#myForm').attr('name','newname')`.

Is it possible to change the form's `onsubmit` function?

Comment: sure, but it is not a good way to do it. Consider attaching an eventlistener to form submit

Comment: How is a form "called"? You mean when it is submitted? Or when it is clicked? Or when the page loads?

Comment: I will change form name, when the button is clicked, Actually BY default it will use for search (so that i gave name as search), If i clicked the button i want to make form for add items to my page so that i can change name as "add" and change "action" and also remove onsubmit function and add new onsubmit function

Comment: What prevents you from just trying it?

Comment: Thanks all, I got it by using button instead of using submit button.

Answer (score 14):

To just change the form onsubmit event you could do this:

```
 $('#myForm').attr('onsubmit', 'return somethingElse()');
```

But you probably want to *remove* the form's onsubmit attribute then *add a new event* using jQuery (note: [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) will remove only event handlers attached by jQuery):

```
 $('#myForm').removeAttr('onsubmit').submit(function(e) { /* your logic here */ });
```

Comment: From documentation: As of jQuery 3.0, `.unbind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.off()` method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Comment: Thanks @Paul You might consider leaving that comment under https://stackoverflow.com/a/7008263/1430996

Answer (score 7):

You can remove an existing event using jQuery's `unbind` function, eg:

```
$('#myForm').unbind('submit');
```

will remove all `onsubmit` events from `#myForm`. Then you can add a new event using normal jQuery:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) { /* your logic here */ });
```

Comment: I believe unbind() will remove only event handlers attached by jQuery